# How to apply Ensemble Feature Selection in Weka?

Tags: feature-selection, ensemble-learning, ensembles

How can we apply *Ensemble Feature Selection* in Weka platform?

**Edit 01:**
This paper applied *Ensemble Feature Selection* using Weka, but I do not know how to do it.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9316747

Comment: Have you contacted the authors of the paper regarding code/setups?

Comment: Actually no. I will.